# android sqlite...Get count in many-many relationship

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to achieve a particular data structure in my android app. A many to many relationship in sqlite.

In my app an `Album` is a collection of `Images` (basically a named grouping, Like a sort of tag) which means an `Image` can be part of different `Albums` and hence the many to many relationship.

My representation however is:

```
-- Album table
_id | name
-------------
1   | Ankara
2   | Laces
3   | Scarfs
4   | Agbada

-- Image table
_id | name      | uri
-----------------------
1   |           | uri1
2   | name2     | uri2
3   |           | uri3
4   |           | uri4
5   |           | uri5
6   |           | uri6
7   |           | uri7
8   |           | uri8
9   | imagename | uri9

-- AlbumImage table
-- This table contains the relationship between albums and images
_id | album_id | image_id
-----------------------
1   | 1        | 1
2   | 2        | 2
3   | 2        | 3
4   | 2        | 4
5   | 1        | 4
6   | 3        | 4
7   | 3        | 6
8   | 1        | 9
9   | 1        | 8
```

I want to query for album data and append a column with the number of images each one has.
So the required result will look like:

```
-- Desired result after query
_id | name   | num_photos
--------------------
1   | Ankara | 4
2   | Laces  | 3
3   | Scarfs | 2
4   | Agbada | 0
```

This is my current SQL query which is **INCORRECT** (note the commented out part)

```
SELECT
    _id,
    name,
    (SELECT
--1     Albums.name  -- When using only subquery uncomment to add albumName column
        COUNT(*)
        FROM 
            Albums,
            AlbumImages,
            Images
        WHERE
--2         Albums._id = 2 AND
            album_id = Albums._id AND
            image_id = Images._id

    ) AS image_count
FROM 
    Albums 
--3WHERE
--4 _id = 2;
```

Which gives me something like:

```
_id | name   | num_photos
--------------------
1   | Ankara | 9
2   | Laces  | 9
3   | Scarfs | 9
4   | Agbada | 9
```

When querying for a single item (uncomment 2, 3 and 4) the mainquery-subquery combo works perfectly.

When querying for a single item with ONLY subquery (uncomment 1 and 2 only, run subquery) it works for album entries that have relationships in the AlbumImages table (id 1, 2 and 3 like

`1 | Ankara | 4`

)but returns a null Album.name for id 4 which does not have a relationship like

`| NULL | 0`

1. I'm not exactly sure how to phrase the entire SQLite statement to give me the desired results. I am trying my possible best to use only a **single query statement** as the data is meant to be used by an adapter to populate a recyclerview.
2. If there are easier ways of doing this (easier relationship, easier queries), please let me know.

Comment: You want to learn about JOINs: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Comment: For an easier way to manage many-to-many relationship in your object model and avoid writing low-level SQL statements, check [JDXA ORM](http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/mapping_many_2_many.html).

Comment: @DamodarPeriwal I understand but this is also a way to learn Sqlite personally.

Comment: @efeturi, Sure, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a._id, a.name, count(album_id) from
album a left outer join AlbumImage ai on ai.album_id = a._id
Group By a._id
```

What you're basically doing is taking all the rows in albumImage and matching them to the rows in album based on the album_id.

Here's an explanation of joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

The group by will merge all rows with that _id.

Comment: Thank You! I thought about this initially but I couldn't implement it. I still have a problem with this solution however **ie** It omits the last Album (id = 4) as it's not in the AlbumImages table (it doesnt have any Image relationships). What I want really is a list of the Albums with their ids, names and number of images

Comment: See my edit. I made it a left join instead of an inner join. A left join makes sure every row from the first table appears in the join result, even if it has no matches in the second table.

Comment: Ah, I see. Lemme test the left join.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN didn't work for me. It appears Sqlite supports only a limited subset of joins as stated [here] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm). Specifically INNER, LEFT OUTER and CROSS JOINs.

Comment: Left outer join should be the same thing as a left join. Sorry got my sql syntax mixed up.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that was what you meant and tried it anyway. It still didnt give me the desired result, which is include the Album with id = 4. My takeaway from the answer is the GROUP BY keyword though. I didnt even know how to use that.

Comment: Bear in mind that I had to switch the order of the tables. Did you try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104333/discussion-between-jason-bray-and-efeturi).

Comment: Yup, This Works! Thanks